# NodeJS + MySQL: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, node.js

Таблица MySQL `counter`:

```
create table counter (
    key bigint not null primary key,
    count int default '1' null
);
```

Записей в таблице ~ 400 000 шт.

Задача: увеличить счетчик (поле count) по ключу (поле key). Ключ key либо уже существует в таблице, либо необходимо добавить новую строку с новым key и значением счетчика count=1.

Логика Javascript NodeJS:

```
const amount = 365 // значение для добавления к счетчику
getKey(key)
.then(keyCount => { // пришло значение keyCount - текущее значение count по ключу key
    if (keyCount > 0) { // 0 - если нет ключа (count нулю равняться не может)
        // Здесь делаем UPDATE по ключу key, прибавляя amount к count
        // ...
    } else {
        // Здесь делаем INSERT нового ключа со значением счетчика = 1
        // ...
        // МЕСТО СРАБАТЫВАНИЯ EXCEPTION (catch error)
    }
})
```

Функция, осуществляющая select из базы (Javascript NodeJS):

```
const getKey = key => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    execute("SELECT `count` FROM `counter` WHERE `key`='" + key + "'") // запрос к базе через npm модуль mysql (v.2.15.0)
    .then(response => resolve((response.length > 0 && _.has(response[0], 'count')) ? parseInt(response[0].count) : 0))
    .catch(error => reject(`ОШИБОНЬКА! ${error}`))
})
```

ПРОБЛЕМА! Вылетает исключение:

`ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '.....' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Ключ в базе существует, значение счетчика также существует, но npm модуль `mysql` возвращает `[]` как результат комманды SELECT. Это нормально?

Comment: Запрос к базе через npm модуль mysql (v.2.15.0)!!!

Comment: [/offtop] Если поле `count` имеет `default '1'` и только инкрементится - то какой смысл делать его nullable?

Comment: По сабжу - зачем огород городить, если существует `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? Он сам всё проверит, или либо вставит, либо увеличит, без всяких "ценных" указаний и прочих ненужных проверок со стороны клиента.

Comment: Поле может увеличиться не на единицу ,а на 365, например (как в коде написано). Пробую: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Да какая разница насколько именно... если это не константа - её передашь в запрос как параметр.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - ПОМОГ! Однако не понятно, на чем спотыкается npm модуль mysql v.2.15.0